# Using JDA, I want to create a warning system for my bot

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am trying to code a warning system for my bot in JDA. I don't know how to go about, whether or not to use a mySQL library, or JSON, and I need help.

Thanks!

Comment: First off, neither I nor anybody else will give you the full code.

If you explain what you want, someone might be able to push you in the right direction and give you advice on how to handle or manage certain parts of your system.

So what do you want? What is the warning system for? What do you want it to do?
Explain the system you want and describe all the features you want to have.

Comment: I want to know, how can I store the warnings that people have. Would I use mySQL, or JSON, or what? I know how to give a warning, that is simple, but I don't know _how_ to store it.

Comment: Personally I would go for the database. Which one you use is up to you.